# how to use like operator in elastic search?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

How can I search a data in elasticsearch. I mean If I putt any data in text field than the related data from that word should be search and displayed.
    What I have tried:

```
$name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name'); 

if(isset($name) && !empty($name)) /*checking condition */
{
    $searchParams['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['term'] ['couchbaseDocument.doc.name']= '*$name*';  /* elasticsearch query for filter the partial name
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "is not working"?  An error message?  Wrong results? Nasal Daemons?

Comment: @J.V.A no error. I think query is not running.

Comment: Is it that your comment is not closed: `/*checking condition` ?

Comment: @J.V.A. sorry for that.. nw its open. if possible rply me asap. i m waitng and if possible provide me another way also.

Comment: What you have shown doesn't actually run the query, you're just setting up the parameters of the query.  You need a lines like: `$client = new Elasticsearch\Client();` ... `$result = $client->search($searchParams);`  Maybe this page http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-elasticsearch-in-php/ is a help?

Comment: @J.V.A. thanks for this link but i want to use like operator . so pls give me example of like operator.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html

Comment: @J.V.A. see below this query is working but according to the prefix word.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public function ajaxhandlerAction() {

        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

        switch ($method) {
        case "searchgroups":
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
        $client = new Elasticsearch\Client();
        $searchParams = array();
        $searchParams['index'] = 'data';
        $searchParams['type'] = 'couchbaseDocument';
        $searchParams['from'] = 0;
        $searchParams['size'] = 20;

         if (isset($name) && !empty($name)) {
           $searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['query']['multi_match']['query'] = $name;
           $searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['query']['multi_match']['type'] = "phrase_prefix";
           $searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['query']['multi_match']['fields'] = ['name', 'city', 'state', 'country'];
           $groupResults = $client->search($searchParams);
                            }
                }
                     break;
                    default:
                     break;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If u need to search like What you have mentioned then we can use the NGRAM Tokenizer , which will divide the single word in a different number of characters.Please find the below link to analyze your tokens.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Then u can simply use a match query:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/indexName/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "FIELDNAME": "YOURTEXT"
      }
   }
}'
```